# Databinding in the controller using spring throws exception

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a controller with method parameter as model say

```
public Response create(Customer customer){
   }
```

Customer model :customer model looks like

```
  @JsonTypeInfo(  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,property = "type")  
 @JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = Config.class, name = "IPC")}) 
 public class Customer(){
 private String type; }
```

1. From swagger UI if i send type as IPC its works fine, but any other value than IPC throws an 400 exception while binding.How can i catch this exception    inside controller

Answer (score 0):

try to use the @ExceptionHandler annotation

The documentation of Spring 4 (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) states that

> The HandlerExceptionResolver interface and the
>   SimpleMappingExceptionResolver implementations allow you to map
>   Exceptions to specific views declaratively along with some optional
>   Java logic before forwarding to those views. However, in some cases,
>   especially when relying on @ResponseBody methods rather than on view
>   resolution, it may be more convenient to directly set the status of
>   the response and optionally write error content to the body of the
>   response.
>
> You can do that with @ExceptionHandler methods. When declared within a
>   controller such methods apply to exceptions raised by @RequestMapping
>   methods of that controller (or any of its sub-classes). You can also
>   declare an @ExceptionHandler method within an @ControllerAdvice class
>   in which case it handles exceptions from @RequestMapping methods from
>   many controllers. Below is an example of a controller-local
>   @ExceptionHandler method:

So, in your controller you can have a method like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public String handleArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<ObjectError> errors = e.getBindingResult() .getAllErrors();
    //you can get the exception e,
    //you can get the request
    //handle whatever you want the then return to view 

    return "your view that you will handle the exception";
}
```